# ansible copy - temp dir too small - how to bypass?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible's builtin `copy` in order to copy a file to my host.

```yaml
- name: "Copy"
  copy:
    src: dump.zip
    dest: "{{ dest_path}}" #lots of space on dest partition
```

The destination path is on `/data` partition with lots of space available.

However, ansible first copies my file to a `/home/myansibleuser/.ansible/tmp` folder, which is kept on a much smaller `/home` partition

so it fails: `[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on ...`

I see no option for the `copy` module:

- to set an explicit temp dir
- or to bypass the temp dir altogether

What is the right way to solve this, without increasing the size of my `/home` partition?

Comment: Take a look here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10703/ansible-temp-dir-change

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for